# Adding a path to PATH variable faster

Tags: windows-7

What is fastest method to add or remove a folder path to PATH variable in windows 7 or is there any utility that make it a bit faster(e.g. right clicking on the folder and selecting "Add/Remove to/from PATH variable")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://patheditor2.codeplex.com/. It's excellent.
Also see this blog post: http://op111.net/82/

[image]

Here is a more advanced tool: www.rapidee.com/

Answer (score 1):

`set` retains change only for current batch process and it's children.

`setx`, on the contrary, makes persistent changes to user or system wide environment.

But it has some issues. See [adding PATH with SETX or PATHMAN or something else?](https://superuser.com/questions/268287/adding-path-with-setx-or-pathman-or-something-else). It suggests [pathed](http://www.p-nand-q.com/gtools/pathed.html) as the most convenient way.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it via the command prompt

```
set PATH=%PATH%;\\path\to\dir
```

After your session, you will need to logoff and log back in to automatically unset it.

Comment: This will only affect the instance of the command prompt you type this into + any children it spawns.  It will not affect the path seen other processes, including those started via the Start menu.