# Using setx to append to user PATH

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, environment-variables

My attempt:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;%~dp0"
```

How do I do this without everything in system PATH getting duplicated in user PATH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the PATH user environment variable from command-line](http://superuser.com/questions/601015/how-to-update-the-path-user-environment-variable-from-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I do this without the system PATH getting duplicated in user PATH?

Use the `/m` option.

```
setx /m PATH "%PATH%;%~dp0"
```

Notes:

- `/m`  - Set the variable in the system environment HKLM.
    (The default is the local environment HKCU)

---

#### `setx` usage

```
F:\test>setx /?

SetX has three ways of working:

Syntax 1:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]

Syntax 2:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]

Syntax 3:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]

Description:
    Creates or modifies environment variables in the user or system
    environment. Can set variables based on arguments, regkeys or
    file input.

Parameter List:
    /S     system          Specifies the remote system to connect to.

    /U     [domain\]user   Specifies the user context under which
                           the command should execute.

    /P     [password]      Specifies the password for the given
                           user context. Prompts for input if omitted.

    var                    Specifies the environment variable to set.

    value                  Specifies a value to be assigned to the
                           environment variable.

    /K     regpath         Specifies that the variable is set based
                           on information from a registry key.
                           Path should be specified in the format of
                           hive\key\...\value. For example,
                           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\
                           Control\TimeZoneInformation\StandardName.

    /F     file            Specifies the filename of the text file
                           to use.

    /A     x,y             Specifies absolute file coordinates
                           (line X, item Y) as parameters to search
                           within the file.

    /R     x,y string      Specifies relative file coordinates with
                           respect to "string" as the search parameters.

    /M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
                           the system wide (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
                           environment. The default is to set the
                           variable under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER
                           environment.

    /X                     Displays file contents with x,y coordinates.

    /D     delimiters      Specifies additional delimiters such as ","
                           or "\". The built-in delimiters are space,
                           tab, carriage return, and linefeed. Any
                           ASCII character can be used as an additional
                           delimiter. The maximum number of delimiters,
                           including the built-in delimiters, is 15.

    /?                     Displays this help message.

NOTE: 1) SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.

      2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
         will be available in future command windows but not in the
         current CMD.exe command window.

      3) On a remote system, variables created or modified by this tool
         will be available at the next logon session.

      4) The valid Registry Key data types are REG_DWORD, REG_EXPAND_SZ,
         REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ.

      5) Supported hives:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM),
         HKEY_CURRENT_USER (HKCU).

      6) Delimiters are case sensitive.

      7) REG_DWORD values are extracted from the registry in decimal
         format.
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).

Comment: Thanks, I need it to be set for the HKCU environment though

Comment: Ah. See this answer [How to update the PATH user environment variable from command-line](http://superuser.com/a/601034)

Comment: I think you should add a big, bold all-caps text stating that `setx /m PATH` can put the system in an unstable situation, mainly when there is a space in the path.

Answer (score 2):

**[CMD, WMIC, HKLM, HKCU, SETX, PATH, 2001]**

the problem is probably more than 20 years old:

- **setx Path "%Path%;NewPath"** pollutes the user path with the system path.

- **setx Path "%Path%;NewPath" /M** pollutes the system path with the user path.

- **the pollution**: [video](https://streamable.com/yp43co)

I am not sure if there is a safe native solution that contemplate NON-ANSI directories making exclusive use of the command prompt.

this is my attempt!

- using Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.868]

**0** - check the paths

```
echo %Path%
reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v Path
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
reg EXPORT "HKCU\Environment" UserEnvironment.reg /y
reg EXPORT "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" SystemEnvironment.reg /y
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "username='<SYSTEM>' AND name='Path'" get  variablevalue
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "username='%COMPUTERNAME%\\%USERNAME%' AND name='Path'" get  variablevalue
```

**tip**: `wmic ENVIRONMENT get *` [to see more]

**info**: a registry backup was performed using the above commands. the files have been saved in the current directory.

**1** - backup user path at `%USERPATH%`

- the commands pre-suppose:

- non-null path;
- functional path;

- if **null** or **unfunctional** path **do only** step "**2**"

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "username='%COMPUTERNAME%\\%USERNAME%' AND name='Path'" get  variablevalue | more +1 > %temp%\userpathvalue.txt
```

**info**: there is some pollution* at the end of the string.

`set /P USERPATH=<%temp%\userpathvalue.txt`

- add `'/'` to better see spaces

`set "USERPATH=%USERPATH%/"`

**[info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)**

- remove up to 15 end spaces, then remove '/'

```
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:        /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:    /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:  /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH: /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:/=%"
```

**info**: the number of spaces introduced was NOT consistent in my tests.

```
echo %USERPATH%[checking final string]
setx USERPATH "%USERPATH%"
```

* when dealing with invisible characters it is easier to identify them by converting them to hexadecimal, do:

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "username='%COMPUTERNAME%\\%USERNAME%' AND name='Path'" get  variablevalue | more +1 > %tmp%\0 && set /P TEMPREADER=<%tmp%\0
echo %TEMPREADER% >%tmp%\1 && echo %TEMPREADER%/ && certutil -f -encodehex "%tmp%\1" "%tmp%\2" 11 | more +4 && type "%tmp%\2"
REM to open on notepad, type: certutil -f -encodehex "%tmp%\1" "%tmp%\2" 5 &&  cmd /C START "" /MAX notepad %tmp%\2
```

**tip**: use 4, 5, 10, 11 (same as none) in encodehex

**[see](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa)**

**2** - set¹²³ user path as `%USERPATH%` only

`setx PATH ^%USERPATH^%`

done!

¹ **info**: `setx PATH "%USERPATH%"` sets the variable **value** instead of the **literal** `%USERPATH%`;

² **info**: using the literal is better, because the behavior becomes dynamic instead of static. i.e., by using the literal instead of the value, only the `%USERPATH%` variable needs to be changed in the future. whereas, by using the value (i.e., the addresses present inside the variable), the `%PATH%` user variable must also be updated upon change in `%USERPATH%` [which is not desirable].

³ **info**: below methods NOT recommended! it works, but it is easier to make mistakes.

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" /v PATH /d ^%USERPATH^% /f
wmic ENVIRONMENT set name="PATH", variablevalue=^%USERPATH^%, username="%COMPUTERNAME%\\%USERNAME%"
```

**3** - for now on just use `%USERPATH%`

`setx USERPATH "%USERPATH%;ENTER-NEW-PATH-HERE"`

**tip**: close all programs, especially terminals, before continuing.

**4** - re-check

```
echo %Path%
reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v Path
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "username='<SYSTEM>' AND name='path'" get  variablevalue
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "username='%COMPUTERNAME%\\%USERNAME%' AND name='path'" get  variablevalue
```

**5** - visual check

`rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

**info**: the system PATH can only be changed if the previous command was launched with administrative privilege;

**6** - **TL;DR**: *do it!* / `or don't!`

```
REM the commands pre-suppose
REM - non-null path;
REM - functional path;
REM if null or unfunctionl path don't progress!

reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v Path
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path

reg EXPORT "HKCU\Environment" UserEnvironment.reg /y
reg EXPORT "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" SystemEnvironment.reg /y

wmic ENVIRONMENT where "username='%COMPUTERNAME%\\%USERNAME%' AND name='Path'" get  variablevalue | more +1 > %temp%\userpathvalue.txt
set /P USERPATH=<%temp%\userpathvalue.txt

set "USERPATH=%USERPATH%/"

set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:        /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:    /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:  /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH: /=/%"
set "USERPATH=%USERPATH:/=%"

echo %USERPATH%[checking final string] && echo %USERPATH% > %tmp%\0
certutil -f -encodehex "%tmp%\0" "%tmp%\1" 11 | more +4 && type "%tmp%\1"

setx USERPATH "%USERPATH%"

setx PATH ^%USERPATH^%

echo done!

REM setx USERPATH "%USERPATH%;ENTER-NEW-PATH-HERE"

REM please close all programs
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this page may cover what you are trying to do:
[adding PATH with SETX or PATHMAN or something else?](https://superuser.com/questions/268287/adding-path-with-setx-or-pathman-or-something-else)
Or maybe add more detail to your question, so we can understand how this is different.  However, that page has multiple solutions to either the same or a similar problem as to what you are asking.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid getting pathed or using the machine env vars